# ASP.Net core modular approach areas vs projects

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture, modularity

I am working on web application in ASP.Net Core. The application will consist from core part (which will be used by every user) and multiple modules.

At the beginning there was a plan that will every module have two separate projects ([module].Core and [module].Infrastructure. What is better approach (from memory consumption side) to have two separated projects for every module or simple separate modules logic in Areas? What are your experiences?

Thank you for all recommendations.